# My Django Python code is not changing the database record

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I'm creating an auction site and I want to be able to change the data in a table to change the price to the new bid. I'm kind of new to Django and Python so I must be missing something.  Right now I'm not getting any errors - it's just not changing the data in the DB.  Does anyone see the issue?

Here is my HTML and Python code (the relevant parts).  I also added the urls.py file in case something needs to be added there for bid?  I don't think so since it's not linking to another page.

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("auction", views.auction, name="auction"),
    path("watchlist/<str:username>", views.watchlist, name="watchlist"),
    path("categories", views.categories, name="categories"),
    path("post/<str:title><str:description><int:price><str:category>", views.post, name="post"),
    path("bid/<str:username>", views.bid, name="bid")
]
```

views.py:

```
def bid(request, username):
    print(username)
    price = request.POST.get("price")
    itemID = request.POST.get("itemID")
    newBid = request.POST.get("newBid")
    title = request.POST.get("title")
    
    query = Bid.objects.filter(itemID = itemID).first()
    
    if(newBid > price and username != query.highestBidder):
        query2 = NewPost.objects.filter(title = title).update(price = newBid)
        new = Bid.objects.create(itemID = itemID, newBid = newBid, highestBidder = username)
        new.save()
    
    query3 = Bid.objects.all()
    print(query3)
    return render(request, "auctions/post.html")
```

models.py:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    itemID = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    newBid = models.IntegerField()
    highestBidder = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

post.html:

```
<h2>{{ p.title }} - Category: {{ p.category }}</h2>
<p>Price = ${{ p.price }}</p> <div>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form name="bid"
          action="/bid/{{user.username}}"
          method="post" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" name="newBid" placeholder="Enter New Bid">
            <input autofocus class="form-control" type="hidden" name="itemID" value={{p.title}}{{p.price}}>
            <input autofocus class="form-control" type="hidden" name="price" value={{p.price}}>
            <input autofocus class="form-control" type="hidden" name="title" value={{p.title}}>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Place Bid">
    </form>
```

Comment: I think that your if statement might simply not work properly: ```if(newBid > price and username != query.highestBidder)``` are you sure that always ```username != query.highestBidder```. Try to remove if statement temporarily and see if database is updated then.

Comment: it should be OK right?  If there's nothing to the query then it will be None.  If username != none then it will work.  seems the only way it will work is if the usernames don't match.

Comment: It didn't work with the if statement out either.

Comment: I even took out the code and just put username = "hi" and print(username) and it's not even printing that out when I click bid.  For some reason, It's not activating the bid.  Do I need to put bid in my urls.py file even though it's not going to a new link? Why would it not activate bid?

Comment: Are you sure then that your form is being submitted?

Comment: it doesn't look like it...by why not?

Comment: You may need to add proper action to the form <form action="URL">,  form should submit to some URL which is connected to view. If you don't add action, it submits to the same URL where you are.

Comment: what if I want it to stay on the same url, though?

Comment: I don't mind where the URL sends me for now - It's just not doing any of the posting to the db.

Answer (score 0):

`query2 = NewPost.objects.filter(title = title).first().update(price = newBid)`

the `update` method is just for a queryset(more than one instance), remove `.first()` and will update all NetPost with that title with the new price.

like this: `NewPost.objects.filter(title = title).update(price = newBid)`

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting the same issue - it does nothing - no errors, though.

Comment: you don't have a url that match with `views.bid`

Comment: with the view do I have to create a bid.html page? I updated my view above and nothing happens

Comment: change this url `path("bid", views.bid, name="bid")` for this `path("bid/<str:username>", views.bid name="bid"),`

Comment: i updated my code and now i'm getting an error saying NameError name "Bid" is not defined.  How can that be true?

Comment: did you import the model `Bid` in views.py? `from .models import Bid`

Comment: That worked! I knew it was something simple. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't import the Bid model in views.py